# Инсталятор скрипта , платная лицензия

Tags: php, yii2, лицензирование

Подскажите как сделать свой продукт платным с выдачей лицензией на него.

К примеру есть работающий продукт на YII2 который планируется продавать, как правильно сделать не совсем понятно где разместить код  и как выдавать лицензию на продукт может кто поделиться собственным опытом возможно реализация какого то инсталятора ?

Comment: Посмотрите на проект IonCube (http://www.ioncube.com/)